# Bulk update attribute on multiple models in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple `has_many` association, and I want to change an attribute from `public` to `private` the associated object.  What's the best way to do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

user = User.first #=> #<User...>
user.posts.count #=> 100
# something like this:
user.posts.bulk_update_attribute("privacy", "private") #=> 1 DB call
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all).

In your example, you'd rewrite it to be something like

```
Post.update_all("privacy = 'private'", ["user_id = ?", user.id])
```

Or as @jenjenut233 points out

```
user.posts.update_all("privacy = 'private'")
```

Comment: Nice. I guess I should have assumed that!

Comment: Note that this does not perform validations/callbacks (which may or may not be a problem). You can also write `user.posts.update_all(privacy: "private")`